# Reason Behind the name for Jungle-River Metric.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, terminology

The Metric defined by $d(x,y)=|x_2-y_2|$ if $x_1=y_1$
and  =$|x_2|+|y_2|+|x_1-y_1|$ if $x_1 \neq y_1$ ; where $x=(x_1,x_2)$ and $y=(y_1,y_2)$ is called the Jungle-River Metric.

Is there any special reason for calling this Metric by this name?

Comment: From [What makes the jungle river metric deserving of its name?](https://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/showthread.php?t=2239843) (my first Google search result): “Imagine the x-axis as a river. Everywhere else, there is thick undergrowth which makes movement impossible in every direction except perpendicular to the river. So, to get from (a,b) to (c,d), one has to move "down" to meet the river at the point (a,0), sail along to the point (c,0), and then head back up through the undergrowth to the point (c,d). This gives the "distance" |b|+|a-c|+|d| (for a, c distinct).”

Comment: A nice Geogebra [animation](https://www.geogebra.org/m/FddDg7Ew) showing the paradoxical balls in this distance.

Comment: Named after the famous paper of John Jungle and Ron River dealing with modelling topographical maps as a weighted lattice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it it explained [here](https://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/showthread.php?t=2239843): imagine the $x$-axis as a river. Everywhere else, there are lots of plants, so that walking on any direction is very hard. So, your best option for going from $(a,b)$ to $(c,d)$ is:

- to move “down” or “up” to meet the river at the point $(a,0)$
- to sail along to the point $(c,0)$
- then to go (again, “down” or “up”) through the jungle  until you reach $(c,d)$.

This leads to the “distance” $|b|+|a-c|+|d|$.

Comment: A nice paper [here](http://ftp.math.uni-rostock.de/pub/romako/heft67/szaz67.pdf)

Comment: @José Carlos Santos Thanks ! But one more thing , is there any connection with the open balls in this metric with the name ?

Comment: If you are asking whether the name “Jungle-River metric” has something to do with what the open balls look like with respect to it, I don't think so.